# Room query with Join

Tags: android, sql, join, android-room

I'm trying to get a list of **A-object** like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tableA " +
       "INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id " +
       "WHERE tableA.name LIKE :arg0")
fun search(query: String): List<A>
```

The query works if I'll comment "INNER JOIN..." string. My data classes are:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tableA")
data class A(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: Int = 0
    // other columns
)
```

And

```
@Entity(tableName = "tableB",
        foreignKeys = arrayOf(
                ForeignKey(entity = A::class,
                        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                        childColumns = arrayOf("tableA_id"),
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
        )
)
data class B(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: Int = 0,
        // other columns,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "tableA_id") var tableAId: Int = 0
)
```

Can someone give me a tip why the JOIN QUERY doesn't work for me?

Comment: Do you get compile time errors or null is being returned from function in Dao or what is exactly not working?